UX guidelines for Employee Mandatory read/ Reading confirmation on Intranets
I'm currently working on a feature for an intranet called mandatory read or reading confirmation. There are two group of users. 1- Admin who sets up and track the mandatory reading page. 2- Employees who need to confirm that they've read the content. I had access to 5 users, and most of them expressed frustrations at the scrolling and reading + checkbox model. Also quizzes were not a preference as it added more work for the employees. Another concern from admins was that they didn't wanted to annoy their co-workers with multiples notifications and reminders. Does anyone's have tips, resources, or guidelines in that field? Much appreciated!

This is a very broad question. Please break it down into smaller parts if you can. Some parts of this question may even fall under company policies which will be difficult to answer as a UX problem.

OK thanks for the tips!

If the employees complain about the long text and you/your company wants to make sure ("force") they read it, you have two options (the third is a special case):

If the consent is critical to the company: Make it relevant like a contract they need to sign (not by checkbox). Maybe even print one page which states "I hereby guarantee I have read and understood the long text. Signed _______" and make it mandatory to file this to HR/admins whom this may concern.

Give a synopsis of the full text in a few bullet points which covers the contents and is sufficient to understand everything instead of reading all the text. I am thinking of "EULAs" here as an example.

If the text is not critical but could come in helpful later to understand processes and procedures: Make it a "read on demand" instead of a "mandatory read beforehand". Meaning: Provide easy access to it and enhance navigation by adding subsections and table of contents etc. If at some point something comes up everybody can say: "Hey, pls read section 3 of the project documentation". And the user will go and gladly appreciate the availability of the document. (Can also be combined with the synopsis to have a quick overview at the beginning and read details later)



Amazing thank you for your help really insightful!
